# ORACLE - check if time is in between two timestamp

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a simple query which will return either A or B depending on the projected oven out date and time. If the projected oven out date and time is between 6am and 6pm, A should be returned. Otherwise B if time is between 6pm and 6am of the next day. My problem is that I do not know how to display A or B depending on the projected oven out date and time. I am using the query below to get the projected oven out date and time.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT
           to_char((ti.txndate + pm.baketime/24),'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS PM') FCSTDOvenOut
    FROM CONTAINER c
    JOIN movin movin ON c.containerid = movin.historyid
    JOIN product p ON c.productid = p.productid AND p.attr_016 IN ('TEST', 'TR')
    JOIN productbase pb ON p.productbaseid = pb.productbaseid
    LEFT JOIN otherdb.pkg_main pm ON TRIM(p.brandname) = TRIM(pm.pcode)
    LEFT JOIN employee e ON movin.employeeid = e.employeeid
    JOIN trackin ti ON c.containerid = ti.historyid AND ti.txndate > movin.txndate
    LEFT JOIN employee em ON ti.employeeid = em.employeeid
    ;
```

Example:

[image]

Thanks for helping everyone.

Comment: 1. what's the question ? 2. Please post only the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   case when
       to_char(ti.txndate + pm.baketime/24,'hh24') between '06' and '17' then 'A'
                                                                         else 'B'
   end shift,
 ....
```